# Guzzle returns 500 error

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-passport

So im new to guzzle and building API's , I have used Laravel Passport and on one GET call its fine. I have written a POST call and getting a 500 error in return

Post function

```
  public function newsSingle() {
            $request = (new GuzzleHttp\Client)->post('http://138.68.180.100/news/article/single', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.session()->get('token.access_token'),
                    'post_id' => $_POST['post_id']
                ]
            ]);
            $news = json_decode((string)$request->getBody());
            return view('pages.newsingle', compact('news'));
}
```

Which does add the post item
POST Data
post_id 
"3"

on the other end I have

Route:

```
Route::post('news/article/single', 'ApiController@singlePost')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Controller function:

```
public function singlePost(Request $request) {
        $article = Articles::where('id', $request['post_id'])->get();
        return $article;
    }
```

my error:

```
Server error: `POST http://ipaddress/news/article/single` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8" /> <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow (truncated...)
```

Comment: Then you must check the error message in the logs of the site. "Internal Server Error" means "The programmer screwed up something which I won't tell you, but gonna store it in the log file so that he knows the details and how to fix it".

Comment: Make sure that debugging is set to true in your .env so you can see your error.

Comment: So I turned on Debuggin on both apps and still dont see the laravel error and trying to find error logs in Nginx is painful

Comment: This could be a whole host of things ranging from a simple typo in the code to a mis-match in your db structure.

If these are single apps, then ensure debugging is on at the API end as well as your own, the error will be logged where the 500 error occurs, not where you are trying to consume the API.

Comment: So I have the API end and the other both debugging and I get nothing, The route and controller work on the api end, I simply get this one error when calling, Could it be something to do with CORS??

Answer (score 7):

We found the similar issue with Guzzle for External API calls when response code is `500` and got `Server error:` and exception is thrown. There is a work around to do a bypass mechanism by catching the exception due to `BadResponseException` to return as response. below is the code for performing this. :)

```
catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
    return $e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();
}
```

Comment: This works on my side.

Comment: This is not working for me :(

Comment: For me the issue was just a typo in the URL.

Comment: this solution for my case return an empy string any suggestion